# Code working not as expected in string splitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this.

```
 df['category'] 
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
Name: category, dtype: object
```

I want applying the below code and splitting them to 2 columns as `level1` and `level2`

**Code**

```
if df['category'] is None:
    riskc = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Level1', 'Level2'])
else:
    riskc=df['category'].str.split(',', expand=True).melt()['value']\
          .str.split(':', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Level1', 1:'Level2'})
```

**Current Output**

```
riskc

    Level1
0   None
1   None
2   None
3   None
```

**Expected Output**

riskc

```
    Level1      Level2
0   None        None
0   None        None
1   None        None
2   None        None
3   None        None
```

What is wrong in my code

Answer (score 1):

To check if df['category'] contains all Nones, you need to use:

```
if df['category'].isna().all():
    riskc = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Level1', 'Level2'])
```

Comment: Works, what was the mistake I made

Comment: You are comparing df['category'] to None but df['category'](even when all of its elements are None) is a Series and not a None.